Walds identity and difference of stopping times
The Walds identity says that if $X_1, X_2, \ldots$ are iid with finite mean and $N$ is a stopping time with $\mathbb E[N]< \infty$ then $\mathbb E[\sum_{i=1}^N X_i]=\mathbb E[N] \mathbb E[X_i]$. Now suppose that $N_1$ and $N_2$ be two stopping times with $N_1>N_2$ and I want to evaluate $\mathbb E[\sum_{i=1}^{N_1-N_2}X_i]$. Can I say that
$$\mathbb E[\sum_{i=1}^{N_1-N_2}X_i]=\mathbb E[\sum_{i=1}^{N_1}X_i]-\mathbb E[\sum_{i=1}^{N_2}X_i]=(\mathbb E[N_1]-\mathbb E[N_2])\mathbb E[X_i]?$$
I am skeptical of this because this question says that the difference of stopping times is not a stopping time and hence we cannot directly use Walds.

If I understand correctly, you are skipping the important step.  Are you wanting to ask whether $$\mathbb{E}\left[\sum_{i=1}^{N_2} X_i\right] = \mathbb{E}\left[\sum_{i=N_1-N_2+1}^{N_1} X_i\right]?$$  Obviously, if this is is true, then the rest of your argument goes through, but I doubt it holds.  Even though both sums "have $N_2$ iid terms", we should still have to contend with the fact they're stopping times, so my gut says it's false.

I see I thought  this should be true for iid $X_i$

Do you mind an example such that $N_1 \geq N_2$ instead?  I have a simple example of where that intuition fails, but we might have $N_1=1=N_2$.

Consider the following (it technically doesn't match your requirements because $N_2 \leq N_1$, but I hope that doesn't matter much):

$X_1, X_2, \ldots$ is a an i.i.d. sequence of Bernoulli random variables with $p=1/2$.
$N_2$ is the first $n$ such that $X_n = 1$.
$N_1 = 2N_2-1$.

Then $$\sum_{i=1}^{N_2} X_i = 1 \\ \sum_{i=N_2}^{2N_2-1} X_i = 1 + \sum_{i=N_2+1}^{2N_2-1}X_i \geq 1$$
so they only have equal expectations if $\sum_{i=N_2+1}^{2N_2-1} X_i = 0$ almost surely.  This, however, is false.
